# Is there a way to construct a file object from file descriptor in lua5.1?

Tags: lua, posix

I am using lua5.1 to write some scripts that need to communicate with other processes, but I find that the example code of *luaposix library* seems not to work as expected, so I wonder if there is a way to construct a file object from file descriptor in lua5.1?
Code and the error message are as below:

```
local fdopen = require "posix.stdio".fdopen
local STDOUT_FILENO = require "posix.unistd".STDOUT_FILENO
stdout = fdopen(STDOUT_FILENO, "w")
stdout:write("INIT")


ngrams chisel error: [string "description = "Record all the n-grams"..."]:90: calling 'write' on bad self (FILE* expected, got userdata)
```

Comment: Is standard output actually what you want? If so, then why not just use `io.stdout` instead of messing with raw FD's at all?